# Dynamically include jsp file with JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to us JS to create a new select element that looks like this:

```
<select name="component1" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selected...</option>
    <%@ include file = "common/select_options.jsp" %>
</select>
```

I have been able to create the element apart from the:

```
<%@ include file = "common/select_options.jsp" %>
```

How can I add the include file statement to my select element? I have tried (select is the name of the element):

```
select.innerHTML = "<%@ include file = 'common/inventory_type_dropdown.jsp' %>"
```

Comment: Hi , you can use `ajax` or `load` method to achieve same .

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Are you trying to include a JSP file in another JSP file? Because you don't need to use any fancy things like ajax or load.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to inlcude a JSP file in another JSP file when a Javascript function is called